# Laravel response download broke my zip file

Tags: laravel, download, response

I have the following code

```
  public function download($uuid)
    {
        $downloads = Downloads::where('uuid', $uuid)->firstOrFail();
        if (Storage::disk('local')->exists($downloads->file->path . $downloads->file->name)) {
            $downloads->counter = $downloads->counter + 1;
            $downloads->save();
            return Storage::download($downloads->file->path . $downloads->file->name, $downloads->file->original_name);
            // return response()->download(storage_path('app/' . $downloads->file->path . $downloads->file->name, $downloads->file->original_name));
        }
        return abort(404);
    }
```

And the Route can be found here: `Route::get('download/{uuid}', 'DownloadsController@download');`

My problem is when I download a zip file I can't open the file. I got an alert which says: Windows can't open the file. I visit both file (the original and the downloaded) with notepad and in the corrupt file I saw one line break in the first row. I deleted that first row and the file can be open now. What's wrong with my script why does it takes one blank line tot he file?

Answer (score 0):

I found the sollution, I had a helper file which had line break before the opening